# Turning on language detection using Tika Server?

Tags: apache-tika

I'm trying to do language detection using Tika Server. Is there a way of requesting this?

Comment: When you say "Tika Server", do you mean the JAX-RS server, or the tika-cli in server mode?

Comment: The tika-cli in server mode.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't do much digging around this topic, but I needed this feature in a Docker setup. The [official documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS#Metadata_Resource) isn't really helpful, but it seems this is now available via the `/meta` endpoint - at least in 1.14. Example usage:

`curl -T file.txt http://127.0.0.1:9998/meta --header "Accept: application/json"`

Response will be similar to:

```
{"language":"en", "Content-Encoding":"ISO-8859-1","Content-Type":"text/plain; charset\u003dISO-8859-1","X-Parsed-By":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser","org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"]}
```

For my particular need, I've used [this](https://github.com/LogicalSpark/docker-tikaserver) Docker image.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just start the Tika CLI Server as normal, with the `--language` flag as your option

eg in one window do:

```
$ java -jar tika-app-1.4.jar --language --server 1234
```

Then in another do:

```
$ nc localhost 1234 < test.txt 
en
$ nc localhost 1234 < spanish.txt
es
$ nc localhost 1234 < french.txt
fr
```

Pass in the text, and you'll get back the detected language

For the full list of the different modes that the Tika CLI supports, just run it with `--help`

Comment: I was able to do this with the tika-app, but am not seeing the correct options to do this with the tika-server. Is there an endpoint that can give me language?

Comment: @Vic The Tika Server currently doesn't have an endpoint for that, but it'd be pretty quick to add. I'd suggest you raise it as [an enhancement in the Apache Tika JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA/), and hopefully one of the JAXRS experts can add it in for you!

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.apache.tika.language.LanguageIdentifier;

public class Test
{
    /**
     * Tika language detection. Take a glance to the org.apache.tika.language.LanguageIdentifier class API.
     * @param args Command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sTextFr = "Texte en français. Il doit être assez long pour permettre l'analyse.";
        String sTextEn = "This is an english text.";
        LanguageIdentifier lin = new LanguageIdentifier(sTextFr);
        System.out.println(String.format("Language (french sentence): %s", lin.getLanguage()));
        lin = new LanguageIdentifier(sTextEn);
        System.out.println(String.format("Language (english sentence): %s", lin.getLanguage()));
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to solve the question - the OP wants to use the Tika App CLI in Server mode for language detection, not write Java code